# How to catch error on http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have some http.get code that looks like this

```
http.get(url, function (response) {
    var data = '';
    response.on('data', function (x) {
        data += x;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(json);
    });
});
```

How do I error handling this if an invalid URL/API endpoint is provided?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can  handle http.get errors  by check  state `error`  example:-

```
http.get(url, function (response) {
        response.on('error', function (err) {
          //do some thing , error  handling
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

you can validate the `url`  by
 **validating response code** & **ping domain or url**

1 - validate response code :-

```
http.get(url, function (response) {
   if(response.statusCode !== 200){
     //error happens
   }
    });
```

2- ping on the giving url  using this repo  [valid-url](https://github.com/ogt/valid-url):-

```
var validUrl = require('valid-url');

if (!validUrl.isUri('apiUrl')){
   //error not valid url 
}
```